# How can I insert only unique data into Postgres using Knex?

Tags: javascript, database, knex.js

I am creating a simple 'attendance' database where a student will only be allowed to 'check in' once per day. Each checkin will include an user_id, name, time, and DATE. Using Knex, how can I only allow one checkin per student per day.

I have attempted several variations of 'whereNotExists' from [this thread](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/1322) but nothing seems to work.

Currently this is my insert statement:

```
db('checkins').insert(db
.select(attrs.user_id, attrs.user_name, attrs.date, attrs.created_at)
.whereNotExists(db('checkins').where('user_name', attrs.user_name).andWhere('date', attrs.date).then(() => {
  console.log('successful insert')
}))
```

I then receive this error ('alice_id' is a test value I used in 'attrs.user_id'):

```
Unhandled rejection error: column "alice_id" does not exist
```

Answer (score 3):

you should validate before insert i.e.

```
db('checkins')
.where({
  user_id: attrs.user_id,
  date: attrs.date
})
.first() // getting the first value
.then((found) => {
   if (found){
     res.json('already present');
   }else{
     // now insert data
      db('checkins')
        .insert({
          // your data
        });
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked, but I ended up changing to use a composite index so it wouldn't fail any race conditions. Like this: 

     table.unique(['user_id', 'check_date']);